# How to redirect from a controller to another controller on Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Trying to do something that should be really easy...
Im using Spring MVC 3 and I want to redirect a call to a controller from inside another controller... ex:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class UserFormController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/method1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectFormPage() {
//redirect to controller2 here, 
//pointing to a method inside it, without going to any url first
}
```

Tried to do that with modelandview but it seems to me that all the solutions have to go through an url first and just then i can redirect to the controller.

thanks for all the help!

=============== more info ===========
The flow is like that: methodA on controller1 is called... do some stuff... and then wants to redirect the user to a listPage... this page has a list of objects, which a methodB on controller2 is able to load and send it to the this listPage. What im trying to achieve is : always that someone needs to get this page, i will call this method onn this controller2 and load it.

Comment: so you want controller2 to return the ModelAndView object? and you want this particular method to not being mapped to an url?

Comment: @reagten No... actually this method on the controller2 is mapped to a page and thats what i want. The thing is: i have to load a list of data before getting into a certain page. Will add more info on description of the problem... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
public String redirectFormPage() {
    return "redirect:/url/controller2";
}
```

Comment: You mean point it to the name mapped on the @RequestMapping ?

Comment: Yes, the URL mapping of your second controller. It will automatically redirect the request to the other controller.

Comment: I tried that with the difference that my controller does not have a @RequestMapping name on it... i named the methods inside this controller, and calling them with redirect does not work. if i name my controller, how can i tell which method i want it to be called?

Comment: If you don't hav a request mapping for your controller, then is it a controller? How is it accessed otherwise?

Comment: if u put an annotation on the controller as controller and a requestmapping just on the method, it s called normally... and this wayu can direct call tje method u want...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do this but this may work:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class UserFormController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private Controller2 controller2;

@RequestMapping(value = "/method1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectFormPage() {
 return controller2.redirectMethod();
}
```

just inject Controller2 and call the desired method

Comment: Hum.. im looking for a better approach then having to inject the constructor inside another constructor... was wondering if the MVC wouldnt have all the methods mapped somewhere so i could call them... added more info to the problem so you can understand why im doing that...

Answer (score 0):

Great question. I like to use struts redirect action result type to avoid putting knowledge of the next view in the actions that handle posted forms.

For example, the action method for a class like `UpdateContactInfoAction` would return `contactInfoSaved` instead of preparing data for the next view and returning `gotoShippingOptionsPage`.  The knowledge that the next step in the flow is to choose a shipping option is only in the struts config.

Anyone know how to do this with Spring MVC?

Comment: this is better use for a comment and NOT for a potential answer as the inquirer specifically asks about Spring. Try to actually guide the user to the answer they need instead.